# Do I really need csrf_exempt in django app view?

Tags: python, django, django-csrf

I have IdP initiated SSO setup where anyone browsing  `https://www.xxxxxx.com` get redirected for authentication to `https://www.yyyyyy.com` and after successful authentication host `yyyyyy.com` POST the SAML Response to callback URL `https://www.xxxxxx.com/SAML`.

urls.py

```
url(r'^SAML$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^home$', views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='https://www.yyyyyy.com', permanent=True)),
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        ...
        return redirect('/home')
    else:
        return redirect('/')


@login_required(login_url='/')
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html')
```

settings.py

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['yyyyyy.com']

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]
```

Everything works when I use csrf_exempt on index view but if I remove csrf_exempt then I get `Cookie Not Set` error. I have 2 questions,

1. Do I really need csrf_exempt on my index view? Or is there any other recommended way?
2. Is the ordering for WhiteNoiseMiddleware and BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware correct?

I am using Django==1.9.5 and Python 3.5.1

Comment: Ordering the middleware seems like a separate question to whether `csrf_exempt` is necessary. The [whitenoisedocs](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/#quickstart-for-django-apps) say the middleware should be above all middleware except security middleware, but you have it below the `UpdateCacheMiddleware`. The [error reporting docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/error-reporting/#errors) say that broken link email decorator should appear above other middleware that intercepts 404 errors. You don't appear to have any of these enabled, so it looks ok to me.

Answer (score 0):

Django checks that the CSRF token in `request.POST` (in the header for ajax requests) matches the CSRF cookie.

For this view, the post request is coming from a different domain, which will not have the token required to pass the CSRF checks. Therefore you need to use `csrf_exempt` for this view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use csrf_exempt decorator because every time it passes csrf token to check in POST request, it is not essential to pass csrf token while login.

**sometimes it may gave the exception for missing csrf or incorrect while login.**

so put as code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def login_to_page():
```

[refer tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt)